# Trigger Maven Build from Eclipse Build

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, build

I have a Maven based Spring MVC project. I want to be able to trigger a Maven build when I right-click on any project and click on "Build Project". As of now nothing happens. However, if I right-click on a project and click Run As...>Maven Build and provide the goal "package", it does trigger a Maven build.

What is stopping it from running the Maven Build when I just click on build project.

Answer (score 0):

This just means that maven has no idea what you want it to do. Running the maven build without specifying a goal, is like running just `mvn` from the command line. this will give you an error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.263s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 29 15:33:36 CAT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/76M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

Note the line that says, **You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal**.

See the link at the bottom of the error message for more explanations. Also you might want to read this [page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) from the maven website.